# Avada WordPress Theme: Rounding corners on dropdown Submenu

Tags: css, wordpress

I´m working on a new WordPress Site using the Avada Theme.
To make the menu a bit more charmful, i want the corners of the Dropdown Sub Menu to be rounded.

So I tried to add the following custom CSS Code:

```
.sub-menu {
border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

Well, that worked and looks good.
The problem i´m facing right now: In one case, I need a additional submenu entry (so a Sub-Sub-Menu). And since I´m using "overflow: hidden" the site won't show me the second submenu.

Do you have any idea how to achieve the rounded corners with working sub menu for a CSS noob?

Thank you for your time, I appreciate your work!

Cheers,

Nick

[Round corners but no Submenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYWsX.png)

[Submenu appearing without custom CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaPyV.png)

```
<li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-6 fusion-dropdown-menu" data-item-id="6" style="overflow: visible;">

<a href="#" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-text">Teamevents</span></a><ul class="sub-menu"><li id="menu-item-1377" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1377 fusion-dropdown-submenu">

//BEGINNING OF SUBMENU

<a href="LINK" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight"><span>Menu 1</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-1127" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1127 fusion-dropdown-submenu">
<a href="LINK" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight"><span>Menu 2</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-371" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-371 fusion-dropdown-submenu">
<a href="LINK" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Menu 3</span></a>

//BEGINNING OF SUB-SUBMENU ONE (won't be shown)

<ul class="sub-menu"><li id="menu-item-338" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-338"><a href="LINK" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight"><span>Submenu 1</span></a></li></ul></li><li id="menu-item-1458" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1458 fusion-dropdown-submenu">

//END

<a href="#" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Menu 4</span></a><ul class="sub-menu"><li id="menu-item-340" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-340">

//BEGINNING OF SECOND SUB-SUBMENU (won't be shown)

<a href="LINK" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight"><span>Submenu 2</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-342" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-342">
<a href="LINK" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight"><span>Submenu 3</span></a></li><li id="menu-item-343" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-343"><a href="LINK" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight"><span>Submenu 4</span>
</a></li><li id="menu-item-344" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-344"><a href="LINK" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight"><span>Submenu 5</span></a>
</li><li id="menu-item-345" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-345"><a href="LINK" class="fusion-bottombar-highlight"><span>Submenu 6</span></a></li></ul></li></ul></li>
```

Comment: Can you add some html code?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! I Edited the HTML Code in the question.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Questions here are supposed to be self-contained, so the minimal code to reproduce the problem belongs directly into your question. See also [Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Comment: @CBroe, minimal code to reproduce the issue and the theme in question is provided as well. Issue asked is not specific to this user only other users of the theme in Wordpress will encounter the issue too.

Comment: @Ugene no, it is not. The actual problem here was due to the bottom border of the links, and the provided CSS snippet does not reproduce that part to begin with. And just referring to a certain theme by name, does again mean the question is _not_ self-contained.

Comment: @CBroe, so does mentioning react.js or vue.js or Javascript (Instead of ECMAScript) mean a question is not self-contained?

Comment: @CBroe Well, than I am even more happy: my problem was solved (thanks again to @Ugene) **and** i learned something for my possibly next question here. Hope we are all good and now have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these instead.

```
.avada-has-mainmenu-dropdown-divider .fusion-main-menu .fusion-dropdown-menu .sub-menu li:last-child a:hover{
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px !important;
}
.avada-has-mainmenu-dropdown-divider .fusion-main-menu .fusion-dropdown-menu .sub-menu li:last-child a{
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px !important;
  border: unset !important;
}
ul.sub-menu {
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px !important;
}
```

A link to the actual site would be good too.

Comment: Hey Ugene, thanks for your help! I tried your code, but it wont round the corners. I edited  the link to the site in the question.

Comment: Sir, you are my hero of the month! Working, thank you so much, really appreciate it!